# RISC-V assembly simulator

Tags: assembly, riscv

I'm trying to learn the RISC-V ISA. Is there a way to simulate RISC-V assembly code just like in MARS for the MIPS ISA?

Comment: I just came across this web-based RISC-V simulator. Very simple and very easy to use: http://ascslab.org/research/briscv/emulator/emulator.html

Comment: This question is basic but focused.

Comment: [venus](https://github.com/kvakil/venus) is another RISC-V instruction set simulator with a web front end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an instruction-level RISC-V simulator with an integrated front end that allows you to interactively edit machine code as well as view and manipulate the CPU state.  I don't know of any tool for RISC-V that is as tightly integrated as MARS, but you can achieve a close approximation by combining some existing RISC-V tools, namely:

- An ISA simulator ([Spike](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim) or [QEMU](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu))
- A RISC-V toolchain with assembler and compiler ([RISC-V GNU toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain))
- A debugger (gdb, included in the above toolchain)
- A debugger front end (gdb tui mode, [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), [gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui), [or others](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends))

I have had luck using QEMU + gdb or gdbgui as follows:

```
$ qemu-system-riscv32 -S -s -kernel /path/to/myprog.elf -nographic
```

Then in another console:

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb /path/to/myprog.elf
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
or
$ gdbgui -r -n -g /path/to/riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb /path/to/myprog.elf
```

NOTE: I notice that the gdb built under the riscv toolchain does not include support for tui mode by default.

NOTE2: QEMU is actually more than an ISA simulator -- it simulates various specific RISC-V target boards and their attendant peripherals.

Answer (score 10):

[Ripes](https://github.com/mortbopet/Ripes) : A graphical 5-stage RISC-V pipeline simulator & assembly editor

[rv8](https://rv8.io/) : RISC-V simulator for x86-64

[risc-v-simulator](https://github.com/ProfessorShaban/risc-v-simulator) : RISC-V assembler/simulator with GUI

[RiscVAssemblerSuite](http://chuckkann.com/students/RISCV_2018/) : RISC V Assembler, Disassembler, and Simulation Environment

[TinyEMU](https://bellard.org/tinyemu/) : TinyEMU is a system emulator for the RISC-V and x86 architectures

Answer (score 7):

While using Spike and the RISC-V GNU toolchain certainly works and it is far from ideal for learning the ISA.

I actually spent a summer porting MARS for RISC-V because there wasn't a good option for beginners to use. [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars) should be exactly what you are looking for.

A few things were removed from MARS for various reasons, but I do keep an eye on the repo so if there is an improvement missing, just make an issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more high-level tool with a graphical interface,
you can have a look at a small tool my university is using for teaching riscv.
It comes with an inbuild assembler and simulator, which displays the content of all registers, memory and the state of a minimal riscv-pipeline for each cycle.

Unfortunatly the project is pretty old and the github-repo is not really up-to-date, but its still a convienient way to start with riscv.

https://github.com/unia-sik/riscVivid

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great RISC-V simulator that was introduced in our computer organization class [BRISC-V Simulator](https://ascslab.org/research/briscv/simulator/simulator.html)

Comment: How does it differ from the [BRISC-V Emulator](http://ascslab.org/research/briscv/emulator/emulator.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I use QEMU for emulation and spike, this is a good chain to test almost everything situation. QEMU also can run Debian.